# How to keep corresponding columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am separating dates by seasons, but I need to keep the corresponding columns in the separate sections. The printed data looks like

```
index       time  DayNum
0     1979-01-01     3.0
1     1979-01-02     3.0
2     1979-01-03     5.0
3     1979-01-04     2.0
4     1979-01-05     2.0
5     1979-01-06     6.0
(this continue for 30 years)
```

Where the time is the date of an event and the DayNum the number the occurred on that day. I am now trying to separate it by seasons, then keep the DayNum column that corresponds with it. 
Currently, I'm using pandas. To get the above chart I did:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

daycoun = 37*365 + 9
yearday = np.zeros(daycoun, pd.Timestamp)
daycount = np.zeros(daycoun) # 9 is number of leap years
for i in range(daycoun):
    test = np.where((dq.iloc[:] >= D1D + pd.Timedelta(days = i)) & (dq.iloc[:] < D1D + pd.Timedelta(days = i+1)))
    daycount[i] = len(dq.iloc[test])
    yearday[i] = (D1D + pd.Timedelta(days = i))
yd = pd.DataFrame({'time':yearday, 'DayNum':daycount})`
```

Please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: categorized time into seasons based on the date with that times DayNum